# server fault: load ssl certificate if access non secure domain (domain.com ) using over the https

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

**Problems:**
I have configured Vhost on apache2,ubuntu 16.04.it is a name based configuration. First one is with ssl-secure but second one is non ssl-secure site.All are working fine if hit in browser address bar **https://www.domain1.com/page1/** and **http://domain2.com/page2/** .
but if i try to access https://domain2.com/page1/ it will through below error if i proceed to unsafe mode page1 is open while it not available on *domain2.com*.

**Expecting:** My expecting behavior is it should not accessible over the https https://domain2.com/page1/ or sand error message page not found (404)

[Your connection is not private Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9xOS.png)

**Vhost Configration Files**

***domain1.com.conf***

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        AccessFileName /var/www/domain1.com/public_html/.htaccess
        # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
        ServerAdmin domain1.com
        ServerName  domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com
        Redirect permanent / https://www.domain1.com/
        # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html
     <Directory /var/www/domain1.com/public_html>                                                           
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews                                          
        AllowOverride All                                                      
        Require all granted                                                     
     </Directory>   
     # Custom log file locations
     LogLevel warn
     #ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-mydomainname.com.log
     #CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-mydomainname.com.log combined

  </VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
       SSLEngine on
       SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
       ServerName domain1.com
       ServerAlias www.domain1.com *.domain1.com
       DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain1.com/public_html"
       SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/domain1.com/public_html/shop/ssl/dhiindia_com.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/domain1.com/public_html/shop/ssl/dhiindia.key"
       SSLCACertificateFile "/var/www/domain1.com/public_html/shop/ssl/dhiindia_com.ca-bundle"

   #SSLCACertificateFile "/ssl/bundle.crt"

</VirtualHost>
```

***domain2.com.conf***

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        AccessFileName /var/www/domain2.com/public_html/.htaccess
        # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
        ServerAdmin domain2.com
        ServerName  domain2.com
        ServerAlias www.domain2.com
        Redirect permanent / https://www.domain2.com/
        # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html
     <Directory /var/www/domain1.com/public_html>                                                           
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews                                          
        AllowOverride All                                                      
        Require all granted                                                     
     </Directory>   
     # Custom log file locations
     LogLevel warn
     #ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-mydomainname.com.log
     #CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-mydomainname.com.log combined

  </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When you ask `http`://domain2.com, it redirects you to `https`://domain2.com.  So https == port 443.  The only VirtualHost listening on port 443 is defined on domain1.com.  So the certificate it serves is for domain1.com.  But since you asked for domain2.com it does not match.  The certificate name must match the requested domain.

Comment: but requested  `http://domain2.com` have not any certificate and i want to do reject if anyone try to access `https://domain2.com`

Comment: There is no VirtualHost defined to respond to https://domain2.com so...  The browser will exchange a certificate on the *:443 VirtualHost, on domain1.com (Apache does not care what domain you ask for until *after* the certificate is negociated).  So the browser will tell the client the certificate does not match the requested domain.  If the client tells the browser to continue anyway, it will then fail.  So don't configure anything, then `https://domain2.com` will not work anyway.

Comment: I have change ip based all ssl secure domain and rest of non ssl domain  are name based.it is working for me.